# How To Get File Directory In C# And show in xml

Tags: c#, xml

this is my cod i want with this get all file in directory and end write all in xml file

```
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);

        string folder = appPath;//Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName) + @"\Archive\";
        string filter = "*.*";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, filter);
        foreach (string item in files)
        {

            string string1 = item;
            string string2 = appPath;
            string  result = string1.Replace(string2, "");
            MessageBox.Show(result);
            doc.LoadXml("<item><name>@" + result + " </name></item>");
            // Save the document to a file and auto-indent the output.
            using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("data.xml", null))

            {
                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                doc.Save(writer);
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

with this code i get my file in directory and remove path 
for example C://folder1/folder2/bin/app.exe
to app.exe
its okay but in the end in xml just write one file
**XML Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<item>
  <name>@\WindowsFormsApplication8.vshost.exe.manifest </name>
</item>
```

Comment: Show the resulted XML

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<item>
  <name>@\WindowsFormsApplication8.vshost.exe.manifest </name>
</item>

Comment: I Have 10 File But In Xml just write one file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

> ```
>         doc.LoadXml("<item><name>@" + result + " </name></item>");
> ```

Every time your loop repeats, you're overwriting all of the XML in your `XmlDocument`.

If you want to use `XmlDocument`, try this instead, although there are other (Cleaner) ways to output XML.

```
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        var root = doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Item"));

        foreach (var item in files)
        {
            var name = root.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("Name"));
            name.InnerText = item;
        }


        var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("data.xml", xmlWriterSettings))
        {
            doc.Save(writer);
        }
```

Using XmlSerialiser (cleaner C# code than XDocument):

```
public class Program
{
    [XmlType("Item")]
    public class Item
    {
        [XmlElement("Name")]
        public string[] Files { get; set; }
    }

    static string SerialiseToXml<T>(T obj, bool isFormatted = false)
    {
        var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        var xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { OmitXmlDeclaration = true, Indent = isFormatted };
        using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder, xmlWriterSettings))
        {
            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType());
            serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] files = {"Apple.txt", "Orange.exe", "Pear.docx", "Banana.xml", "Papaya.xls", "Passionfruit.cs"};

        var item = new Item {Files = files};
        var xml = SerialiseToXml(item, true);

        Console.WriteLine(xml);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note that `XmlWriter.Create` is the recommended way to create a writer instance in newer versions of .NET. I think XmlTextWriter and XmlTextReader are deprecated.

Comment: Tnx For your answer ... i have in my folder another folder but in xml dont write files in another folders how pass it?

Comment: this code calls stringBuilder.ToString() before xmlWriter disposed and flushed

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your items.

Here's the code that will write a proper xml:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        string appPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        string folder = appPath;
        string filter = "*.*";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, filter);

        using (XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("data.xml", null))
        {

            writer.WriteStartDocument();

            writer.WriteStartElement("Items");

            foreach (string item in files)
            {
                string string1 = item;
                string string2 = appPath;
                string result = string1.Replace(string2, "");

                writer.WriteElementString("Item","", result);

                Console.WriteLine(result);

                writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();

            writer.Close();
            doc.Save(writer);
        }
```

And here's the sample xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Items>
  <Item>\ConsoleApplication1.exe</Item>
  <Item>\ConsoleApplication1.exe.config</Item>
  <Item>\ConsoleApplication1.pdb</Item>
  <Item>\ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe</Item>
  <Item>\ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe.config</Item>
  <Item>\ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe.manifest</Item>
  <Item>\data.xml</Item>
</Items>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for best answers.
in my directory too i have 3 folder and There are more files in any folder ,i want any files in folders write in my xml
**For Example**

```
<Items>
  <Item>\ConsoleApplication1.exe</Item>
  <Item>\ConsoleApplication1.exe.config</Item>
  <Item>\ConsoleApplication1.pdb</Item>
  <Item>\ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe</Item>
  <Item>\ConsoleApplication1.vshost.exe.config</Item>
<Item>..folder1\gold.dll</Item>
<Item>..images\exit.png</Item>
```